# setting crontab is not working but crontab -l does via PHP file

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I want to set a cron job using PHP file, but don't know where the problem is coming in my process.

When I wrote below (in PHP file and executed it on browser), it shows me the result. (It lists all cron jobs)

```
echo shell_exec('crontab -l');
```

But when I wrote below line, then it didn't set any cron job:

```
echo shell_exec('crontab /home/testsite/public_html/crons/crons.txt');
```

But If I run the same command (**crontab /home/testsite/public_html/crons/crons.txt**) via puTTY on my CentOS Dedicated Server, then it updates the crons list from crons.txt file.

I also tried passing **-u** as I saw on several stackoverflow questions:

```
echo shell_exec('crontab -u testsite /home/testsite/public_html/crons/crons.txt');
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does the user, you run PHP with, have permission to write/execute (change) the crontab ?

Comment: yes, the user has permissions to do everything. Becuase when I start putty from same user, it does everything

Comment: Do you get an error with the second crontab command? What does the `echo` command echo?

Comment: As pointed by DanFromGermany, are you sure that your web server has permissions to do everything? Including crontab writing? And if you're sure, you may consider serious security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, and the way you are trying to change the crontab is not the best way either. Let me show you how I would do it:

First, get the user you are when executing the PHP by putting into the PHP script:

```
echo get_current_user();
```

Depending on the cron software you use (I use anacron, like most other ppl I guess), you go the cron config directory and put a single file for you up with write access:

```
touch /etc/cron.d/testsite
chown <user from above>:<user(=group) from above> /etc/cron.d/testsite
```

With PHP, you can directly read and write to that file now (`file_get_contents(); file_put_contents()`) and crontab **will immediately use it.**